# How do I connect LowDB in React project?

Tags: database, reactjs

First I apologize for my poor English skills.
I have a question about LowDB.
There is software that I am developing using React + Electron + LowDB.
But when I tried to use LowDB in my project, there was a problem.

lowDB.js

```
const low = require('lowdb');
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');
const adapter = new FileSync('db_data/db.json');
const db = low(adapter);

db.defaults({ data: [] }).write();

class DBHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.db = db;
  }

  insertStudyTime(saveDate, startTime, endTime, restTime) {

  }
}

export default DBHandler;
```

time.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css';
/* lowDB Import */
import DBHandler from '../../lowDB/lowDB';
```

Imported LowDB as above.

The problem was that we could see that running lowDB on node in cmd would work fine.

However, a Type Error occurs on the graceful-fs library used by lowdb:
[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined on fs.closeSync.toString()]

It seems to be a simple problem. I think that there is a part that I am missing. It is difficult to find the answer even if I go through the process while looking at each process, refer to the README of the LowDB repository,

Comment: Please avoid using images to show source code or error messages: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

yarn add lowdb
index.js:

```
import low from 'lowdb'
import LocalStorage from 'lowdb/adapters/LocalStorage'

const adapter = new LocalStorage('db')
const db = low(adapter)

const Home=(props)=>{
    db.defaults({ users: [], token:'' }).write()
    #init db, use db.defaults.

     then you can set db, and get db.
     db.get('users').push({ username: 'admin' }).write()  #set user's username
     db.set('token','you token').write()
     

     get:
     db.getState().user.username   =>'admin' 
     #or  db.get('user').find('username').value()
     db.getState().token    =>'you token'
}
```